# how to search consecutive line number in unix?

Tags: unix

How can we check if **17 lines are consecutive** among large number of lines using UNIX shell scripting ?(we can use the concept of line numbering as each line is different) please also specify to which shell it is working on.
Thanks

Comment: Do the lines already have line numbers in them? It would help to see a sample of the format.

Comment: yes it already has number